# Amazon AWS Signature V4 Java gives Wrong Encoding

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a simple form to POST an object to a bucket in S3 directly from my browser using AWS Signature V4.

I use Java to generate the policy and signature values for the pre-signed form. For now, I just want to test that it works so I don't mind that this is a manual signature generation process.

My Java code is the following

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Lala {    
    static String policy_document = "{ \"expiration\": \"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z\"," +
            "  \"conditions\": [" +
            "    {\"bucket\": \"sigv4examplebucket\"}," +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"user/user1/\"]," +
            "    {\"acl\": \"public-read\"}," +
            "    {\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html\"}," +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"]," +
            "    {\"x-amz-meta-uuid\": \"14365123651274\"}," +
            "    {\"x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"}," +
            "    [\"starts-with\", \"$x-amz-meta-tag\", \"\"]," +
            "    {\"x-amz-credential\": \"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request\"}," +
            "    {\"x-amz-algorithm\": \"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\"}," +
            "    {\"x-amz-date\": \"20151229T000000Z\" }" +
            "  ]" +
            "}";

    static String secret_key = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create a policy using UTF-8 encoding.
        byte[] utf8_policy = policy_document.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Convert the UTF-8-encoded policy bytes to Base64. The result is the StringToSign.
        String base64_policy = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(utf8_policy));

        // Create a signing key.
        byte[] signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key , "20151229", "us-east-1", "s3");

        // Use the signing key to sign the StringToSign using HMAC-SHA256 signing algorithm.
        byte[] signature_bytes = HmacSHA256(base64_policy, signing_key);
        String signature = Hex.encodeHexString(signature_bytes);

        System.out.println(base64_policy);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(signature);
    }

    static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception  {
        byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] kDate    = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
        byte[] kRegion  = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
        byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
        byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
        return kSigning;
    }

    static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception  {
        String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
        return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

The policy document and access/secret keys pair are all taken from the Amazon's example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html).

My code gives back the following Base64 encoded policy:

> 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

and the following signature for it

> 1df5972015a56d4fdef92944436b91ce1f39b5cc684dcce9f4dab74b82734e84

which are different from the ones provided by Amazon in the above link.

Am I missing something? I have a feeling that the String format in the policy_document variable might be messing things up, but no matter how I format it (i.e. new lines, escaping etc.) I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode Amazon's and yours, they are not the same, mainly in formatting. Simple formatting differences will result in a different signing hash.

In your case you need to add newline characters at the end of each line.

Amazon

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

Yours:

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",  "conditions": [    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],    {"acl": "public-read"},    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }  ]}
'
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the quick response. I also generated the encoding with the new lines at the end, but I get this comparison:

https://www.diffnow.com/?report=v5uzl

When decoded, my generated base64 and amazon's, give the same result!!

Comment: In the versions from diffnow there are differences in the line endings, Amazon's has two characters: CR, LF (0x0d, 0x0a) and Java has one character: LF (0x0a). This is why where there are issues hexadecimal needs to be used, it never lies. DiffNow glosses over the line ending issue ignoring the "extra" line ending byte, but SHA uses them all. Sorry, hexadecimal may be old school but it is still alive and necessary for low level problems such as encodings and cryptography. Heck, even my wife reads hex and she is not a programmer.

Comment: Hex is not old school at all! What you say is absolutely right! Thanks again!

Comment: https://github.com/lucasweb78/aws-v4-signer-java is a light weight java library with zero dependencies which makes it easy to create AWS V4 signatures.